# Facebook login blank page iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook login into Objective C based application. Every single configuration has been completed from Facebook developer documentation.

The issue is that I am getting blank view instead of Login view. This is happening in all devices and simulator as well.

Can someone please help to figure this issue out.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

Plist Configuration

```
 <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            </array>
</dict>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>App Name Here</string>

    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
    </array>
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: @Sh_Khan just updated the question with the standard login code snnipet

Comment: Try adding these :   var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)                                                                  I think you are forgetting to add login button on your View controller

Comment: Tried this as well but same result

Comment: Check AppID and display name in Info plist again. These should be correct. Also check you have added the code given by them in this appdelegate method :     func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

Comment: Just double check it's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the solution. Just change the Login behaviour from Native app to FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is in swift but try to convert it , it works perfectly with me

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>id_Here</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>YourAppName</string>

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb_id_Here</string>          
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>



    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logOut()        

    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email", "user_friends"], from:self, handler:
        {


            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in


            let requestMe:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id,email, first_name, last_name, gender, picture"])


            let connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()



            connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler: { (con, results, error) in

                //access_token

                if ((error) == nil)

                {

                    print("fname is 20 : \(results!)")



                }
                else

                {


                }

            })


            connection.start()

            if facebookError != nil
            {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
            }
            else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)!
            {

                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")

            }
            else
            {


            }
    })
```

App delegate

```
 // 9 and later


func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool

{

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String


            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)

    }
    else
    {


           print("cvcvcvcvcvcvcc")


      }

  return true

   }

//ios 8

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {


    print("qoqpqpqpqpqpqpqpqppq45")

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)


}
```

Comment: This look pretty similar to the Objective C version. Actually issue not in the code but somewhere in configuration.

Comment: download facebook app or signout from safari

Comment: Same issue, no luck

Comment: Can you please tell the Info.plist configurations that you have used?

Comment: Added the info.plist configuration in question

Comment: This is the default controller open by Facebook inside the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161612/discussion-between-vinod-singh-and-sh-khan).